# OpsCentre 6 throws error

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

When attempting to initially setup a cluster, I get the following **error**:

```
Error: Consistency validation error: Unsupported or invalid DSE version: 5.0.1
```

Which is weird, because I downloaded the latest version of `DSE` and `OpsCentre 6`.

I see the error, specifically when attempting to create a Config profile and are asked for the version of DSE. if I use a lesser version, for example,

4.8.8;

I can successfully create the Configuration Profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem,
i solved this by restart opscenter

Comment: Thanks. While it seems so simple to solve - it was annoying - especially being a beginner. Thanks!

I noticed also that this error does not occur, using the latest version (6.0) of OpsCenter.